# Why, when calling a method, does it say that I need to catch an exception when I have already caught it?

Tags: java, exception, javasound, audioinputstream

I have a class that loops some audio:

```
public class PlayGameMusic {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try{
            AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("\\Users\\natal\\Desktop\\programs\\APCS\\Fill the Boxes.wav"));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(inputStream);
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        catch(IOException error){System.out.println("IO Exception Error");}
        catch(InterruptedException error){System.out.println("InterruptedException");}
        catch(Exception error){System.out.print("System.out.println("Exception");");}
     }
}
```

I can compile this method and the compiler does not report any errors (I have tested this with print statements). However, when I try to call the main method of the above class (`PlayGameMusic`) in another class...

```
public class RunGame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       PlayGameMusic.main(null);
    }
}
```

...I get this compiler error:

> ```
> unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
> ```

I am catching the possible exceptions and the `PlayGameMusic` class works when run on its own. Why can't I call it from another class?

Comment: What does this do: `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {`, the `throws Exception` part?

Comment: Sorry but this cannot compile: catch(Exception error){System.out.print("System.out.println("Exception");");}

Comment: `catch(IOException error){System.out.println("IO Exception Error");}` BTW - that should logically be `catch(IOException error){System.err.println("IO Exception Error");}` or even better (and shorter) `catch(IOException error){error.printStackTrace();}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've declared your `main` in `PlayGameMusic` to throw `Exception`.  Even if nothing in that method actually throws `Exception` out of the method, you must catch it or declare it in a calling method, e.g. `RunGame.main`.

Because you are catching the exceptions in `PlayGameMusic.main`, you don't need to declare that it throws anything.  In `PlayGameMusic`, change:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 1):

If a method calls another method which explicitly throws Exception, then the calling method should catch that Exception or declared it to be thrown in its own method signature

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97339_01/doc/bc4j/BC4JRuntimeFiles/obcExceptions.htm

Answer (score 0):

If `PlayGameMusic.main` can't throw `Exception` it shouldn't be declared with `throw Exception`. It shouldn't have `throw Exception` just because it can generate *and catch* `Exception`.